# Disable textbox when checkbox is not checked inside a repeater

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asprepeater

In my .aspx, the following elements are inside a Repeater:

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkNormalServiceCost" Checked="true" OnClick="EnableDisableTextBox()"/>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNormalServiceCost" />
```

And in the `<script>` tag there is the jQuery function:

```
function EnableDisableTextBox() {
    $('#chkNormalServiceCost').change(function () {
        if ($('#chkNormalServiceCost').is(':checked') == true)
            $('#txtNormalServiceCost').prop('disabled', false);
        else
            $('#txtNormalServiceCost').prop('disabled', true);
    });
}
```

But still it isn't working.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Sorry, I will consider it in the next questions.

Comment: no worries - just as a side note :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the controls' `id` property is auto-generated when it is rendered; it will not be `chkNormalServiceCost` on the client side. You need to set the `ClientID` property on it instead:

```html
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkNormalServiceCost" ClientID="chkNormalServiceCost" Checked="true" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNormalServiceCost" ClientID="txtNormalServiceCost" />
```

From there you can then add a click handler using jQuery instead of attaching the `change` event after the first `click` has been fired:

```
$('#chkNormalServiceCost').change(function () {
    $('#txtNormalServiceCost').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kbqhbL2q/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. May I do not add the ClientID property in the <asp:...> tag, but in the jQuery to have something like this: #<%= chkNormalServiceCost.ClientID%> ?

Comment: And it shouldn't be any OnClick parameter for the <asp:CHeckBox> ?

Comment: No, avoid the use of `onclick`. For one thing they are outdated - using jQuery allows you to separate your HTML and JS code better. Also, you should be using the `change` event on checkboxes for better accessibillity.

Comment: I tried to declare: var chkNSC = '#<%=chkNormalServiceCost.ClientID %>'; , but I get ... does not exist in the current context. My .aspx page has only one content...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function EnableDisableTextBox() {
     if ($('#<%= chkNormalServiceCost.ClientID%>').is(':checked') == true)
         $('#<%= txtNormalServiceCost.ClientID%>').prop('disabled', false);
     else
         $('#<%= txtNormalServiceCost.ClientID%>').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnClientClick="EnableDisableTextBox()" instead of OnClick

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkNormalServiceCost" Checked="true" OnClientClick="EnableDisableTextBox()"/>
```

Comment: @Florin M. okie inspect the checkbox  element from browser check the id?? have u used contentplaceholder

Comment: Yes, I'm using ContentPlaceHolder

Comment: @Florin M.  ok inspect the element and find the checkbox id in browser whether it have same id in browser and code

Comment: When inspecting it , the id is like: cphMain_rptBNNormalServices_chkNormalServiceCost_1.

Comment: @Florin M.  fine use like this

$('#cphMain_rptBNNormalServices_chkNormalServiceCost').change(function () {
    $('#cphMain_rptBNNormalServices_txtNormalServiceCost').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});

Comment: But should I use the ClientID?

Comment: Okie no problem u first check the function works or not
1. go to browser console and see the error...
2. Place alert in empty function whether the function executes or not at the time of click
3.